# How to display and update deep nested values in React state

Tags: reactjs

**The React State** 
`const [config, setConfig] = useState([])` (populated with the data visualised below)

**The data inside the config state** 
The data includes several deep layers of nested arrays with objects
[image]

1. I need to display all the fields in a input (i've done this with nested .map functions)
2. When a user types in any free text inside the input it should update the original state(config)

What's the best practice to achieve this behavior? Currently I'm quite clueless on how I can update the values through the input fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an option for you but you could use something like [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview) which supports paths for it's form fields.

> To access nested objects or arrays, name can also accept lodash-like dot path like social.facebook or friends[0].firstName

An example:

```
import { Formik, Field } from 'formik';

function MyForm() {
    return (
        <Formik>
            <Field name="a.deeply.nested.path[0]" />
        </Formik>
    );
}
```

Comment: I will look more into this solution. Thank you.